# how to get a specific object from an ArrayList<abstract class>?

Tags: java, arraylist, abstract-class

So my application has a customers class which have an ArrayList.
So for example, some customers will have traveling insurance and some will have home insurance and car insurance.

i am trying to get the details of the insurances printed out in a gui, but i have problems accsessing the specific insurances at will.

In my gui i want one page to show traveling insurance and another to show boat insurance from the same customer. My trouble is that when i get my arraylist, i dont know the order of the inurances and as i result ive made methonds in my customer class

```
class Customer {
    private String name;
    //and so on

    private ArrayList<AbstractInsurance> list;

    public CarInsurance getCarInsurance () {
        for (insurance i : list) {
            if (i.getName().equals("Carinsurance") {
                returnt (CarInsurance) i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However this seems like bad practise as i dont think the customer class should have responsibility to find a specific insurance. And also it will return nullpointer whenever a customer wants to se insurance they havent aquired.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you think the method shouldn't be there, then put it elsewhere, where you think it should be. And if you want to avoid an NPE, then check if the insurance is null before using it.

Comment: Perhaps a `java.util.Map<String, AbstractInsurance>` rather than `ArrayList`? The map key is the insurance name. If an entry doesn't exist in the map for a given key, e.g. _Carinsurance_, then method `get()` of interface `Map` will return null, thus avoiding the `NullPointerException` that concerns you in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are many ways to solve this but here is my way. From your code I draw the conclusion that a customer only has at most one of each insurance so I would use an enum and a Map instead

```
enum InsuranceType {
    CAR,
    BOAT,
    HOME
    // and so on...
}
```

And then I would store the insurance object with the enum in a map in the Customer class or similar since it is per customer

```
Map<InsuranceType, AbstractInsurance> insurances = new HashMap<>();
```

and a method to access them

```
public AbstractInsurance getInsurance(InsuranceType type) {
    return insurances.get(type);
}
```

This method can of course return null but you need to handle that when calling it since it can not be avoided.

If you want you can also add convenience methods to get a specific insurance like

```
public CarInsurance getCarInsurance() {
    return (CarInsurance) insurances.get(InsuranceType.CAR);
}
```

For Java 8 and later you can let the methods return Optional to avoid null pointer exception problems

```
public Optional<AbstractInsurance> getInsurance(InsuranceType type) {
    return Optional.of(insurances.get(type));
}

public Optional<CarInsurance> getCarInsurance() {
    return Optional.of((CarInsurance) insurances.get(InsuranceType.CAR));
}
```

Comment: Of-course for JDK 8 and above, method `getCarInsurance()` could return a `Optional<CarInsurance>` thus alleviating the need to check whether the method returned null or not.

Comment: @Abra True, thanks for the input. I'll add a Java 8+ solution as well

Answer (score 0):

This would be a way to do it:

```
class Customer {
    private String name;
    //and so on

    private List<AbstractInsurance> list;

    public Optional<CarInsurance> getCarInsurance () {
        return list.stream()
                   .filter(insurance -> insurance instanceof CarInsurance)
                   .findFirst();        
    }
}
```

Then checking if the Optional.isPresent().

But rather I'd re-think the solution, like as suggested use a Map, modify AbstractInsurance to include an Enum with the insurance type...